# How to force a WPF ComboBox to show its items list?

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a Button and a hidden WPF ComboBox. When the button is pressed, the ComboBox must be shown and be ready to select an item from its list.

How can the ComboBox drop down list be forced to show programmatically?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To open the drop down.

```
    combo.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
ComboBox1.DroppedDown = True
```

Comment: That's form WinForms, I'm asking for a WPF ComboBox. I believed the WPF tag was sufficient, now I see the context must be more explicit :)

Comment: No, just the WPF tag is sufficient.